# Django Error on edit in Django admin

Tags: python-3.x, django-2.0

When I try to change one of my models in the django admin I am getting the below error. 
Here is my model.

```
class Scan(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to = 'images/', default = 'images/')
    R = models.IntegerField(255)
    G = models.IntegerField(255)
    B = models.IntegerField(255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    clean = models.NullBooleanField(null=True, default= False)
```

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  574.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  223.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
  1553.         return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  62.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  58.                 return func.**get**(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changeform_view
  1450.             return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in _changeform_view
  1482.             if form.is_valid():

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  179.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
  174.             self.full_clean()

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  378.         self._post_clean()

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in _post_clean
  401.             self.instance.full_clean(exclude=exclude, validate_unique=False)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in full_clean
  1151.             self.clean()

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/api/scan/add/
Exception Value: 'bool' object is not callable

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding clean, which is a func in the model. Rename that variable.